# environment specific log4j configuration by spring

Tags: spring, log4j

I am loading log4j.xml using the traditional way

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:conf/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This works fine but now I need to load a different log4j.xml file based on which environment I am in which is defined by a environment variable/jndi entry .. so I was hoping that with new spring 3.1 property management I could just change this to

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:conf/log4j-${ENV-NAME}.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and spring will load the correct log4j file in each environment but this doesnt works probably because web.xml is loaded before spring. I came across this method

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
<property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
<property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
<property name="arguments">
 <list>
  <value>log4j-${ENV-NAME}.xml</value>
 </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

so essentially moving configuration of log4j into spring context file instead of web.xml. But this doesnt works either for some reason logging gets enabled in a way that everything is logged. So how can I use a different log4j.xml file based on an environment variable or loading it programmatically in the servletcontextlistener.

Comment: are you also using maven ?

Comment: @Jintian DENG yes i am

Comment: Then I will suggest using maven profile. Check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543219/how-to-config-maven-for-different-log4j-properties-in-different-envirements

Comment: i just ended up configuring it programmatically

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
   String env = ResourceUtils.getEnvironment();
   //load log4j configuration file for this enviromnentt
   String log4jFile = "/WEB-INF/classes/conf/log4j-" + env.toLowerCase() + ".xml";
   DOMConfigurator.configure(sce.getServletContext().getRealPath(log4jFile));

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's too late to help adeelmahmood, but hope others will benefit from my answer.
The thing is adeelmahmood was right, this configuration:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:conf/log4j-${ENV-NAME}.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

is working, but:

- Log4jConfigListener should be registered before ContextLoaderListener in web.xml !!!
- You must also remember that Log4jConfigListener assumes an expanded WAR file.

Then, if ENV-NAME environment variable is set, it works as expected.

By the way, ${ENV-NAME} can be used in spring config files as well! That's not everything... You can also use our env.property to set spring profile:

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
 <param-value>${ENV-NAME}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This way you can set log4jConfigLocation and spring profile, both with one and the same env. variable.

BTW and just in case: using Maven profiles to have separate builds for dev, test and production isn't good practice. Read eg. http://java.dzone.com/articles/maven-profile-best-practices and remember: "Use profiles to manage build-time variables, not run-time variables and not (with RARE exceptions) alternative versions of your artifact".

Comment: Thanks for coming back and doing this, Gave me just the information that I needed to get this working in my application.

Answer (score 0):

This might help too for more recent readers: in Log4j 2.7 (but it's probably older) the parameter name has been altered:
see interface `Log4jWebSupport` :

```
/**
 * The {@link javax.servlet.ServletContext} parameter name for the location of the configuration.
 */
String LOG4J_CONFIG_LOCATION = "log4jConfiguration";
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Boot picks up the native configuration from its default location for the system (such as `classpath:logback.xml` for Logback), but you can set the location of the config file by using the `logging.config` property.

`logging.config=classpath:log4j-<ENV-NAME>.xml`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-logging.html