# Executing multiple maven profiles

Tags: java, maven-3

I'm trying to execute multiple maven profiles using maven commandline

```
mvn clean process-resources -P<Profile1>,<Profile2>
```

But it only executes for Profile2, Profile1 is never executed. Help is required on executing multiple profiles through commandline.

Also note that when I list active profiles, it shows both profiles as active.

Comment: Can you paste here you pom.xml ?

Comment: Think this is related : [Build multiple profiles in one go (Maven-2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932944/maven-build-multiple-profiles-in-one-go) and [build multiples artifacts with different classifiers at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320322/build-multiple-artifacts-with-different-classifiers-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn clean install -P profile-1,profile-2
```

This should work fine. profiles doesn't have to be explicitly active.