# How to invoke a maven profile multiple times with different system properties

Tags: java, maven, system-properties, maven-profiles

I have around 15 maven profiles which are identical except that they have different systemPropertyVariables in their configuration. I would like to execute them all with a single command, and I know I can use this: [Executing multiple maven profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027526/executing-multiple-maven-profiles)

Is it possible to do this without having to list all the profiles in the maven command, i.e. can I make a single profile within my POM file that, in turn, invokes multiple profiles? Alternatively if I could execute a single profile multiple times with different systemPropertyVariables, that would work too.

Comment: Are you sure that profiles are the right tool for this job? Different executions of some plugins might be feasible too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate a profile depending on a property. This can be the same property for many profiles, so using something like `-Dsomeprop=true` on the command line can activate many profiles for you.

That said, having 15 profiles is quite unusual and you should analyse whether your construction is too complicated.

Comment: Do you have any code snippets/examples of using -Dsomeprop=true, or how this would be implemented?

Comment: See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html for the different ways to activate a profile.